# "Replace" in Where Clause SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room

Can you not use REPLACE in a where clause in sqlite? Googling didn't answer, just found a bunch of example of how to update a table using REPLACE. Here's what I'm doing:

```
select * from TableName where :parameter = REPLACE(column_name, '-', '')
```

And getting

```
<expr> expected, got 'REPLACE'
```

Using Android Room Library

Comment: `REPLACE` is word #98 on the reserved words list.

Comment: Not really what I'm looking for though...REPLACE is not the name of my column. I'm trying to utilize it in a WHERE clause.

Comment: Whoops, sorry about that! If you try this without Room (e.g., using a plain SQLite client, or `SQLiteDatabase` directly), does it work? If so, it may be a matter of Room's SQL parser not handling it.

Comment: No problem! I have not but I can give that a shot...I'm wondering if that's what it is, it seems a little weird to me that you wouldn't be able to do it.

Comment: Well, Room needs to parse the SQL statement in order to properly handle the parameters; that parser may have limits. And I'm not sure that your syntax would work with plain SQLite. That would equate to `select * from TableName where ? = REPLACE(column_name, '-', '')`, and I'm not sure that SQLite supports parameters on the left-hand side of the conditional expression. You might try inverting the order there (`REPLACE(column_name, '-', '') = :parameter`) and see if that behaves better.

Comment: Well I ran it just for kicks (still using Room) and despite the red squiggly line and error message, it apparently parses fine, because it returns the expected result (matching my parameter with -'s removed). So I guess it works!

Comment: It's possible then that the problem is limited to a Lint check in Android Studio. AS 3.0 seemed to add some Room-specific improvements for `@Query` annotations (syntax checks, code-completion, etc.). Anyway, glad to hear that it is working!

Comment: Good to know! And thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in Android Studio 3.0.x code analyzer and as mentioned in the comments, has no runtime impact - the SQL works just fine.

There's a similar bug reported in Android issue tracker that has been marked fixed in Android Studio 3.1: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/68293745

Answer (score 0):

my SQL skills aren't amazing but is this not an UPDATE?

```
UPDATE table SET column_1 = new_value_1 WHERE search_condition
```